# Why not message show

Tags: asp.net-3.5, devexpress

My Project have master page .On my content page i write the bellow syntax

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControlUserRole" runat="server" CloseAction="CloseButton" 
    EnableClientSideAPI="True" HeaderText="Confirmation" Modal="True"  
    PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter"
    ShowCloseButton="True" AllowDragging="True" EnableViewState="False">

    <ContentCollection>
<dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server"></dx:PopupControlContentControl>
</ContentCollection>

</dx:ASPxPopupControl>


  private void ShowMessage(String Message)
        {
            if (Message != "")
            {
                PopupWindow Winddow = new PopupWindow(Message);
                Winddow.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
                ASPxPopupControlUserRole.Windows.Add(Winddow);
            }
        }
```

Under the button event event i call the **ShowMessage** method.But i can not see the message.Why not message show?

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, but try to improve your English; it's a key asset as a programmer, because you will be coding and communicating in English

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine here.  I added your code to the content page and the Confirmation window appears when a button is clicked.  So, the problem is somewhere else...  I am afraid, it is impossible to help you having only this code.